# How should I store tag hierarchy data in DB for fast retrieval of hierarchy chains?

Tags: sql-server, mongodb, data-structures, database-design, nosql

The data I am dealing with is a hierarchy of tags which are strings and more than writes we would be performing reads. We would be searching for a tag, and for whichever tag the search string is a sub string, we would need to return its full hierarchy with respect to its Root. like if we have the following tree:

---

```
                           Animals
                              |
                     ------------------
                     |                |
                   Tiger             Pets
                               ------------------
                               |                |
                              Dogs             Donkey
```

Incase our search string is "Do" we need to get `Dogs->Pets->Animals` and `Donkey->Pets->Animals`. The data could be pretty large and the searches need to be fastest possible. How should I model the data so as to get the required results. Which is more suitable for this: RDBMS or NoSql?

Comment: Which is more suitable RDBMS or NoSQL- the two are not mutually exclusive.  Hive, for example, offers an SQL interface for retrieving from hadoop.

You need more details on the volume of data and transactions if you're going to get a good answer.  If you're running 1000 transactions per day, use an RDBMS.  Some of the relational systems are beginning to incorporate bigdata capabilities - Oracle has had this since the mid 1990's, DB2 has incorporated "lessons learned" from hbase, and SQL Server is actively working on using hadoop's HDFS as the backing store.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From relational part of the world, there are several ways how you can model and implement hierarchies. You can find in-depth coverage in Joe Celko's Trees and Hierarchies in SQL for Smarties book. For this particular task, I think path enumeration model could work quite well. In this model, you store a path in every node of the tree, so it is easy to search for nodes and output path.
I don't see any issues with RDBMS-based implementation. I'd look on NoSQL if 'large' is actually 'enormously huge'. I believe that searches would be faster on RDBMS.

Answer (score 0):

The decision which technology to use is subjective. There are a lot more things you should consider than just this one query when making this decision. Also keep in mind that there is no such thing as a "typical" NoSQL database. There are dozens of different database technologies which all work differently.

But should you decide to use MongoDB, you can store the tag hierarchy by creating a document for each leaf-node which also includes the full tag-hierarchy of that leaf in an array like this:

```
{
     name:"German Shepherd",
     hierarchy: [
         "Animals",
         "Pets",
         "Dogs"
     ]
}
```

A `find({ hierarchy: "Dogs" })` will return all documents where `"Dogs"` appears anywere in the hierarchy chain. You can create an index on `{hierarchy:1}` which will drastically speed up this query (indexes on arrays create separate index keys for all array entries). MongoDB preserves the order of array entries, so you can rely on the order of the hierarchy array to accurately represent the hierarchy.